# How can I handle an exception based on the RESTRING IN C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a function that parses an XML file within a try and catch statement, so whenever there's an error occurring I catch the XmlException type.
The issue is that I would like to catch the exception and return an error only if a certain kind of exception happen.

I tried parsing different kind of XML bad-formatted and I noticed in the thrown XmlException object that the only thing that differs from the different exceptions is the message, res and restring attributes.
But res and restring are not accessible, and they're the only way I can actually see if the exception is a Xml_BadNameChar error.

I could check the message attribute, but I dont think it's the most elegant way of doing it

Comment: Do you think you could include the exception message (and any info you have about why it's happening) to give us some more context? I don't suppose this exception has an InnerException that you can access for more information?

Comment: Instead of waiting for an exception can you not first look for the “bad-format” you won't tell us about?

Comment: I have two articles on Excption handling, that I like to link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | You can not rely on the message Unfortunately. Between Localisation and fixing of errors, there is just too much that can go wrong. Unless they provided subclasses or properties to indetify the specific cause, I see no reliable option for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to do this on the message. Messages are strings. "Strings are patient". Never store data in the Message. Never try to retrieve it from the message. If the locale change or they ever fix or introduce a spelling mistake, all that code would break.

Caveat: Unless of course you can get the string from the framework. Not sure how to do that, however.

XmlException does not exactly have a lot of non-string properties for the differentiation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlexception?#properties

InnerException, HResult and maybe Data are worth a look.

As for making late/more detailed cecks on the Exception before you decide to handle or throw it on, I give you my TryParse code (writte for someone still locked into 1.1):

```
//Parse throws ArgumentNull, Format and Overflow Exceptions.
//And they only have Exception as base class in common, but identical handling code (output = 0 and return false).

bool TryParse(string input, out int output){
  try{
    output = int.Parse(input);
  }
  catch (Exception ex){
    if(ex is ArgumentNullException ||
      ex is FormatException ||
      ex is OverflowException){
      //these are the exceptions I am looking for. I will do my thing.
      output = 0;
      return false;
    }
    else{
      //Not the exceptions I expect. Best to just let them go on their way.
      throw;
    }
  }

  //I am pretty sure the Exception replaces the return value in exception case. 
  //So this one will only be returned without any Exceptions, expected or unexpected
  return true;

}
```

In all 3 Exception Cases, the handling is the same. But their only common base class was inconvinient - Exception.
I had to catch Exception - way wider then I am comfortable with. But I should have eliminated this overcatching (all the false-positives) with the if. And you can put whatever logic you want there.

Note however that I feel like your Handling code might be poorly structure if you only want some **Xml**Exceptions handeled here.